# Python regex to find alpha strings between dashes

Tags: python, regex

I have a series of strings that all look roughly like this.

`- Conf. w/attorney, defendant, bondsman. Magistrate ct., PA - Research - 2.7 hrs - 86 miles`

I need to write a regular expression that matches the

`- Conf. w/attorney, defendant, bondsman. Magistrate ct., PA -`

and    `- Research -` parts of the string.

But not the `hrs` and `miles` segments.

`x = re.findall('-[.^\-0-9]*-', line)`

Is what I've tried so far, but that doesn't return any matches.

I'm sure I'm just writing the RE wrong.

Comment: it seems that the dash character is used as a delimiter. have you considered using `.split()`

Comment: Haha, you know, that WILL probably be a better idea.

Comment: Yea, that totally fixes all my issues. I dont know why I didn't think about that. . 
I wish there was a way I could accept your comment as my answer.

Comment: I'm glad I helped! No worries about accepting my answer/comment. I'm sure  someone will give you an answer using a regular expression. Feel free to accept that one.

Comment: When all you've got is a hammer, everything looks like a nail. I love/hate when I'm struggling with what seems like a complex issue and someone else is like "Oh, does {more basic method} not work?" and my response is just "Oh right..."

Comment: Yeah, I had to use 3 regexs on a huge file to get this far, and I guess I was just in the regex mindset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do it using Regex, you can try:

```
r'.*?(?= \d)'
```

Check: https://regex101.com/r/uG0fI2/3